# Android - How to properly parse string to float (price number format: integer, decimals or both)

Tags: android, floating-point, number-formatting, decimalformat

I'm trying to parse an input string from the user and convert it into a Float

```
String[] inputs = {
      "100",
            "100.0",
            "100.00",
            "100.00000",
            "100.1",
            "100.10",
            "100.11",
            "100.111",
            "1.0",
            "0.1",
            "0.10",
            "0.1000",
            "0.111",
            "100,00",
            "1,000.15"
    };

    for (String input : inputs) {
        try {
            input = input.replace(",", ".");
            Float value = Float.valueOf(input);

            if (value == 0F) {
                Log.d("APP", "--> NOPE: " + value);
                continue;
            }

            String oldInput = input;

            DecimalFormat dc = new DecimalFormat(value > 1F ? "#.00" : "#0.00");
            input = dc.format(value);
            value = Float.valueOf(input);

            Log.d("APP", oldInput + " -> " + value);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Which gives me the following outputs:

```
100         -> 100.0
100.0       -> 100.0
100.00      -> 100.0
100.0000    -> 100.0
100.1       -> 100.1
100.10      -> 100.1
100.11      -> 100.11
100.111     -> 100.11
1.0         -> 1.0
0.1         -> 0.1
0.10        -> 0.1
0.1000      -> 0.1
0.111       -> 0.11
100,00      -> 100.0
```

The problem appears when I get an input string like this:

```
1,000.25
```

A `java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points` exception is thrown

1. Is `1,000.25` a valid input? (Currency from US?)
2. Is there a better or much more optimized way of parsing the input?

Comment: `,` for formatting , remove it using replace

Comment: 1,000.25 after replacing the characters is 1.000.25 which is not a valid float,
if the ',' is just a visual separator you could change `input = input.replace(",", ".");` to `input = input.replaceAll(",", "");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float result = Float.parseFloat(string.replaceAll(",", ""));
```